# Adding a new column to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have a dataframe **df** with one column and 500k rows (df with first 5 elements is given below). I want to add new data in the existing column. The new data is a matrix of 200k rows and 1 column. How can I do it? Also I want add a new column named **op**.

```
 X098_DE_time  
  0.046104      
 -0.037134      
 -0.089496      
 -0.084906      
 -0.038594
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried from [this page of the pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html).

Answer (score 1):

We can use `concat` function after rename the column from second dataframe.

```
df2.rename(columns={'op':' X098_DE_time'}, inplace=True)
new_df = pd.concat([df, new_df], axis=0)
```

**Note:** If we don't rename df2 column, the resultant `new_df` will have 2 different columns.

Answer (score 0):

To add new column you can use

```
df["new column"] = [list of values];
```